# What is the entry point for git?

Tags: c, git

I was browsing through the git source code, and I was wondering where the entry point file is? I have gone through a couple files, that I thought would be it but could not find a main function.

Comment: What's the entry point of *any* C program?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Although am pretty new to c, I would assume it could be any file with a main function. Let me know if it is otherwise.

Comment: @larsks I will try that thanks.

Comment: you may want to look at git.c, the function cmd_main (line 644) looks like it is early in the call chain. (N.B. I don't have a local copy of the source, so I was browsing the repository online).  Also do a you can do a recursive grep (grep -rne 'main') from the top level of the repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I believe the entrypoint is `main()` in `common-main.c`.

```c
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    /*
     * Always open file descriptors 0/1/2 to avoid clobbering files
     * in die().  It also avoids messing up when the pipes are dup'ed
     * onto stdin/stdout/stderr in the child processes we spawn.
     */
    sanitize_stdfds();

    git_setup_gettext();

    git_extract_argv0_path(argv[0]);

    restore_sigpipe_to_default();

    return cmd_main(argc, argv);
}
```

At the end you can see it returns `cmd_main(argc, argv)`. There are a number of definitions of `cmd_main()`, but I believe the one returned here is the one defined in `git.c`, which is a bit long to post here in its entirety, but is excerpted below:

```c
int cmd_main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    const char *cmd;

    cmd = argv[0];
    if (!cmd)
        cmd = "git-help";
    else {
        const char *slash = find_last_dir_sep(cmd);
        if (slash)
            cmd = slash + 1;
    }

    /*
     * "git-xxxx" is the same as "git xxxx", but we obviously:
     *
     *  - cannot take flags in between the "git" and the "xxxx".
     *  - cannot execute it externally (since it would just do
     *    the same thing over again)
     *
     * So we just directly call the builtin handler, and die if
     * that one cannot handle it.
     */
    if (skip_prefix(cmd, "git-", &cmd)) {
        argv[0] = cmd;
        handle_builtin(argc, argv);
        die("cannot handle %s as a builtin", cmd);
    }
```

`handle_builtin()` is also defined in `git.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's best to address the misunderstanding. Git is a way of collecting, recording, and archiving changes to a project directory. This is the purpose of a *Version Control System*, and git is perhaps one of the more recognizable ones.

Sometimes they also provide build automation, but often the best tools focus on the fewest responsibilities. In the case of git, it mostly focuses on commits to a repository in order to preserve different states of the directory it is initialized to. It doesn't build the program, so the entry points are unaffected.

---

For C projects, the entry point will always be the same one defined by the compiler. Generally this is a function called `main`, but there are ways to redefine or hide this entry point. Arduino, for example, uses `setup` as the entry point and then calls `loop`.

The comment left by [@larks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42195929/what-is-the-entry-point-for-git#comment71553876_42195929) is an easy way to find the entry point when you're not sure. Using a simple recursive search from a git repo's root directory can hunt for the word `main` in any included file:

```
grep main *.c
```

The Windows equivalent is `FINDSTR`, but recent updates to Windows 10 have greatly improved compatibility with Bash commands. `grep` is usable in the version I'm running. So is `ls`, though I'm not sure whether it has been there all along.

---

Some git projects include multiple languages, and many languages related to C (and predecessors) use the same entry point name. Looking only in file extensions of `.c` is a good way to find the entry point of the C components, assuming the code is of high enough quality that you'd want to run it in the first place.

There are definitely ways to interfere with how well the extension filters out other languages, but their use implies very haphazard coding practice.

Comment: Best answer so far!

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer this question (IMO). I think the OP is looking for the entry point of _git itself_...

Comment: @DanLowe Perhaps you're correct, though the answer is highly relevant to this problem and more general problems as well. The only difference is that it's important to identify the build system, which directory it invokes from, and whether it messes with entry points. In most cases finding main is sufficient.